# Simple PHP, show String but encoded, affected in URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, string

how are you today..?

hi all...

I found something odds, and very tricky..

echo "&currency"; //return ¤cy

echo "&ethnic"; //return ðnic

Why is this happened..? its affected on URL query.

it seemed that the string is **encoded** ASCII, how to fix it..?

this is the loop.. tried to replace & to & amp ;

`foreach($pars as $key => $val) $param .= "&amp;".$key."=".$val;`

but its having so many errors...

Thankyou.

Comment: 1. You need to HTML-encode the & character as &amp;.  2. **how are you today** - brilliant

Comment: so.. only need to change & into &amp; ..? how brilliant..!!!

Comment: foreach($pars as $key => $val) $param .= "&amp;".$key."=".$val; ..... so many errors...

Answer (score 0):

You can find this symbol here [https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref.](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Use urlencode() to solve your problem with URL query.

Comment: just a simple string, url already encoded but parameter query has changed, tried to replace with &amp; in my function, its return many errors.. something like this... foreach($pars as $key => $val) $param .= "&amp;".$key."=".$val;

Comment: http_build_query not solve this..

Comment: `http_build_query()`, if used properly, absolutely **does** solve this.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055171/2943403