# & character not encode in URL - PHP Core

Tags: php, mysql

on mysql database one table's column name is a & B. When i fetch data from this column data not shown on screen URL is a%20&%20 but when i put %26 instead of & data are shown.

1. Not shown Data ( http://localhost/dashboard/View-Diploma.php?Course=a%20&%20b )
2. Shown Data ( http://localhost/dashboard/View-Diploma.php?Course=a%20%26%20b )

Php code -

```
<a href="View-Diploma.php?Course=<?php echo $cou_row['CourseName']; ?>
```

try urlencode and change mysql column collation but not work

Comment: This is why modern PHP frameworks include a routing layer.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/nqIpp  I think this answer is worth a read: [php prevent & creating codes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055171/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="View-Diploma.php?Course=<?php echo urlencode($cou_row['CourseName']);?>
```

i insert urlencode now its work